# Intellij: access swing panel

Tags: swing, user-interface, intellij-idea

I have created a `Swing window` in `Intellij`. And there is an `infobox.form`(infobox is the name I've chosen!) created in my project directory. Now when I open my project, I don't know how to access the `swing panel` to edit my `swing form`? I can just open the `infobox.form` file and it is an xml like file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution , `view->enter presentation mode` then `view->exit presentation mode` to go to real size window